# Real-closed fields are the existentially closed ordered fields

Tags: model-theory, ordered-fields

While reading the proof in Shorter Hodges (Thm 7.4.4) that the theory of real-closed fields has quantifier-elimination, I came across the following claim (paraphased):

"Let $A$ and $B$ be real-closed fields and $A$ be a substructure of $B$. If $b \in B$ is algebraic over $A$, then in fact $b \in A$."

I suppose that's fine if you know that the real-closed fields are the existentially closed ordered fields, since the formula saying that a polynomial with coefficients in $A$ has a root is existential, but why are the real-closed fields the e.c. ones?

Perhaps there's some elementary reason that I'm missing in the particular case above?

Comment: What is the definition of a real closed field? Depending on the definition, I think that they are e.c. (for qfree formulas at least) might be trivial.

Comment: It's an ordered field $F$ such that every odd degree polynomial over it has a root in $F$, and either $a$ or $-a$ is a square for $a \in F$.

Comment: Do you know that it's complete?

Comment: "No". I know you can equivalently define them as the ordered fields elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$, in which case completeness is trivial, but I have not seen a proof of this equivalence. It's probably not too bad, though, so I think an argument relying on completeness would still be welcome.

Comment: Well, completeness (and the fact that the reals form a model) easily implies that the only proper algebraic extension is of order $2$, by adding a square root of $-1$, as spelled out by Alex in his answer. A very similar argument is the following: in the reals, the irreducible nonlinear polynomials are exactly the quadratics with negative discriminant. This is clearly elementary and preserved by extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a fact that a field $R$ is real closed if and only if $R$ is not algebraically closed, but $R[\sqrt{-1}]$ is algebraically closed. (The implication from the definition you gave of real closed field to $R[\sqrt{-1}]$ being algebraically closed is the content of the "algebraic" proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra: once you verify that $\mathbb{R}$ is real closed by your definition, it follows from this characterization that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.)

Now if $R$ is real closed, then $R[\sqrt{-1}]$ is the only proper algebraic extension of $R$, since any algebraic extension of $R$ embeds over $R$ in the algebraic closure $R[\sqrt{-1}]$, but there are no intermediate fields in this extension of degree $2$. Thus, if $R\subseteq R'$ are real closed fields, no proper algebraic extension of $R$ is contained in $R'$ (since $-1$ has no square root in $R'$), so every element of $R'$ which is algebraic over $R$ is already contained in $R$.

I'm not sure if this is the explanation Hodges had in mind, since I don't think he states or proves the characterization above in his book. But I do think it's a good way of thinking about this argument.